# How do i get file path of my file in java enterprise application?

Tags: java

I created java enterprise application and it consists of ejb module and web application. I have plain old xml file in source packages folder in package "common" in my ejb module. I want to pass this file path in File() constructor for one class in ejb module. How do i do it?

If i pass any of the below it doesn't work :-

```
new File("abc.xml"); //this take file from glassfish/domains/domain1 :(

new File("./abc.xml");
```

I don't want to pass hardcode path like /home/administrator/appname/module/etc..

I want the path relative from my ejb module. Please help me. I've tried all things.

Actually when i created a class in same folder and then try `classname.getResource("abc.xml").getPath()` it works fine. But what if i don't have any class in that folder. Waiting for your replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you've already guessed, you should use `this.getClass().getResource("/common/abc.xml").getFile()` -- it will work for any class of your application since it uses class loader to locate a resource in class path. See [javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) if you run into trouble.